# What is the most efficient way to prevent PHP class redefinition other than using include_once/require_once?

Tags: php, class

Or in other words, is there a PHP equivalent of the C++ directives #ifndef, #define which are used to accomplish this?

Comment: Something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php

Comment: You should be using the `_once` functions anyway.  If you've been avoiding them because of something you said somewhere about performance, don't believe everything you read on the internet.  The performance was fixed ten years ago.  Also, why not use an autoloader?

Comment: Why not use `include_once/require_once`?

Comment: I'd like to avoid the overhead, if possible. I am about to start a new class and would like to code so as not to need those functions.

Comment: You're worrying too much about overhead.  Don't.  There isn't any.  When you're done, use a profiling tool like xdebug or xhprof to find out where the *real* bottlenecks are in your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figure this will work:

```
<?php

if(!class_exists("MyClass")):

class MyClass
{
    ...
}

endif;

?>
```

This avoids the overhead that comes with require_once/include_once functions.

Comment: No it doesn't avoid any "overhead".  It's going to get executed every time it's included, which is *worse* than just using the `_once` functions.  Let me repeat this again.  **There is no overhead in using `_once`**.  No overhead.  None, nada, zip, zero.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really like conditional including to reduce "PHP symbol table" you can code like C preprocessor directives like this:

```
IF ( !defined( 'MY_CONSTANT' ):
  define( 'MY_CONSTANT', 'PHP C like defined' );
ENDIF;

IF ( !defined( 'header_php' ):
  define( 'header_php', 'PHP "header" defined' );
  include( 'header.php' );
ENDIF;

// you can do this for class, functions, variables etc
```

But on the end will have additional cosntants symbols defined for nothing.